# Angular binding breaking the decimal places

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, decimal

Inside my $scope i have  tobing= 2.00  or tobind=2.20  and i am binding it to

```
  <span >{{datasource.tobind}}</span>
```

I want my  bound display text to be always "2.00"  or "2.20"  with the two last digits but the angular seems to be auto rounding it. Its a workaround to set it to text and to bind it as string but will cause a lot places with logic to cast it to number and then to string which is making the bunny cry. Please suggest how to fix auto rounding.

Comment: try to use like this `<span>{{datasource.tobind| number:2}}</span>`

Comment: Well numbers in JavaScript do not store the trailing zeros. `var x = 2.00` is `2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the [number filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3anumber) or the [currency filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3acurrency).

```
<span >{{datasource.tobind | number:2}}</span>
```

or:

```
<span >{{datasource.tobind | currency}}</span>
```